# Facebook: dialog windows popup - when navigating away, how do I do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

when you enter text into the status box and click on any hyperlink or click on the back button, a dialog window will display the following message "Are you sure you want to leave this page?"?

Does is this done? how do you do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+%22Are+you+sure+you+want+to+leave+this+page%3F%22

Comment: Are you asking how it can be done at you own server or how it is done on facebook? Have you tried anything yet? Inject your code and noop's (_if any_) to your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a dirty flag

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var isDirty=false;
window.onbeforeunload =function() {
 if (isDirty) return "Form not saved";
}

window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("someFieldId").onblur=function() {
    isDirty=this.value.length>0;
  }
}
</script>


.
.
.
```